# Segfault at Py_Finalize (python 2.5) in single threaded C program

Tags: python, c, segmentation-fault, cpython

In this following hello world C program, I am both extending and embedding Python.

**spam.c**:

```
#include <Python.h>

static PyObject *
spam_echo(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {
    const char *command;
    int sts;

    if (!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &command))
        return NULL;
    sts = printf("%s\n", command);
    return Py_BuildValue("i", sts);
}

static PyMethodDef SpamMethods[] = {
    {"echo", spam_echo, METH_VARARGS, "Prints passed argument"},
    {NULL, NULL, 0, NULL}
};

PyMODINIT_FUNC
initspam(void) {
    (void) Py_InitModule("spam", SpamMethods);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    PyObject *args;
    PyObject *arg;
    PyObject *result;
    PyObject *moduleName;
    PyObject *module;
    PyObject *func;

    Py_SetProgramName(argv[0]);
    Py_Initialize();
    initspam();

    PyRun_SimpleFile(fopen("foo.py", "r"), "foo.py");

    moduleName = PyString_FromString("__main__");
    module = PyImport_Import(moduleName);
    Py_DECREF(moduleName);
    if (!module) {
        return 1;
    }

    func = PyObject_GetAttrString(module, "foo");
    Py_DECREF(module);
    if (!func || !PyCallable_Check(func)) {
        return 1;
    }

    args = PyTuple_New(1);
    arg = Py_BuildValue("s", "hello world");
    PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, arg);

    result = PyObject_CallObject(func, args);
    Py_DECREF(arg);
    Py_DECREF(args);
    Py_DECREF(func);

    printf("== before\n");
    Py_Finalize();
    printf("== after\n");
}
```

And here is the Python program invoked:

**foo.py**:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import spam

def foo(cmd):
    spam.echo(cmd)
```

I compile with

```
gcc spam.c -I/usr/include/python2.5/ -lpython2.5
```

with GCC 4.2.4-1ubuntu4 and I am using python2.5-dev package on Ubuntu Hardy.

Basically, I have a segfault at Py_Finalize as shows the output:

```
hello world
== before
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: I actually just found what was causing the segfault! I have to comment out either `Py_DECREF(arg)` or `Py_DECREF(args)`. My guess is that decrefing `args` automatically decrefs `arg` as well, so I would be decrefing `arg` twice. I would still need confirmation or another explanation from someone!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swapping the lines `Py_DECREF(args);` and `Py_DECREF(arg);` solves the problem. The segfault was the result of accessing `arg` from `Py_DECREF(args)` after it was already freed.

Comment: Thankss a lot! That helped!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps swapping lines fixed it for Python2, but it should not have, and certainly won't for Python 3. Look again at the snippet:

```
args = PyTuple_New(1);
arg = Py_BuildValue("s", "hello world");
PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, arg);
```

`PyTuple_New` creates a new object, as does `Py_BuildValue`. If you were to stop there, yes, you should DECREF both.

However, `PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, arg)` steals the reference for `arg`. That means `arg` is now "owned" by the tuple `args`. You are no longer are responsible for `arg` and therefore **should not** DECREF it.

When `args` is DECREF, it will DECREF each of its items, which will take care of `arg`. (Use `Py_REFCNT()`) to verify, if you like.

That means, for example, if you wanted to put `arg` into two lists, you'd need to INCREF it once:

```
args1 = PyTuple_New(1);
args2 = PyTyple_New(1);
arg = Py_BuildValue("s", "hello world");
PyTuple_SetItem(args1, 0, arg);
PyTyple_SetItem(args2, 0, arg);
Py_INCREF(arg);
```

So when `args1` is removed, it can DECREF arg once, without causing a problem with args2.

Note you can INCREF(arg) anywhere after it is created, even after the SetItem -- it's still in scope.